# Rails routing error when try to login using postman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In the last night, everything was working just fine, now I'm starting rails server and try to login but showing like this

> ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant ApplicationController::Resaponse):
>
> ```
> app/controllers/application_controller.rb:2:in `<class:ApplicationController>'
> ```

the app little bit bigger and I'm confused what I have done for this error.

This is my `application_controller` code

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
    include Resaponse
    include ExceptionHandler
    # called before every action on controllers
    before_action :authorize_request
    attr_reader :current_user
    
    private
    
    # Check for valid request token and return user
    def authorize_request
        @current_user = (AuthorizeApiRequest.new(request.headers).call)[:user]
    end

end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the `Resaponse` in `include Resaponse`? I think it will be `Response` if your file name is `response.rb` and the class name is `Response`

Comment: Yes! exactly this was, Thanks! @fool-dev